# How can I actually kick/boot a player?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been in several parties where all three of us go to kick a player (via right-clicking on the player's tile in the upper left corner) and nothing happens. We were only able to kick an idling player once when I stood next to him, selected "Kick", and received a modal window to insert a reason. The rest of the party received the vote and he was kicked.

What are the conditions for actually booting a player? Do you have to stand near him? Does there need to be a period of time in-between the first vote and the actual vote? Is it a majority vote or a consensus vote, and how does it differ between four-, three-, and two-person parties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general consensus is that:

- You have to be close to the player
- You have to wait for a timer after the player joins the game
- And I think that you cannot kick a game creator

Answer (score 3):

Last night I found myself wanting to kick a player afking in town for 15 minutes since he joined. I tried to do it right before engaging some boss fight but nothing happened. But after porting to town it worked - I was presented a screen to provide a reason for a kick, and I assume the other guy got kick-voting dialog, since the player got successfully kicked.

In short: you have to be close to a player being kicked for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Vote kicking is a little glitchy right now.  I think you have to be able to "see" the player to be able to kick them, much like inspecting their equipment and skills.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's an internal game timer for when you join.  It's always the people that join a game and sit in town that I can't ban, after a while (15-20 mins) I've been able to, although at that time I wasn't the one initiating the kick.